# Removing links underline in the gaps

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-4

Sorry form my English.

Hi, I am in some references use [FontAwesome](http://www.fontawesome.io/) and I need between the icon and remove the underlining text links, is there such a possibility?

[image]

```
<p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Username</a></p>
```

Pattern in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jeen/jEh6J/)

Comment: [`text-decoration` is the CSS property you are looking for.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Comment: a {text-decoration:none;}

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not exactly put the question, I do not know very well English, but the user **BillOfUK** understood me and answer all my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space and use padding inside the i tag

```
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a i {text-decoation:none; padding-right:5px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jEh6J/2/

Comment: Everything turned out just enough)). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a {text-decoration:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jEh6J/1/

Answer (score 0):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEh6J/4/)

If you want to remove the line between `a` and `i`, then add a padder: `padding-right`

```
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a i { text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;}
```

Also, remove space before your text "Username". I fixed it in the fiddle anyway.

### Result

[image]